# Printing new pages with e.HasMorePages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, drawing

I'm a little confused how I can use the `HasMorePages` property. I'm trying to print some page more depending by the `YPosition` method, but it causes an infinite loop of printing pages.

This is my code:

```
        private float YPosition()
        {
            return this.TopMargin + ((float)this.LinesCount * this.Font.GetHeight(this.Graphics) + (float)this.ImagesHeight);
        }

        private void TicketPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
            this.Graphics = e.Graphics;
            foreach (Tuple<Object, LineTypes> tuple in this.Objects)
            {
                switch (tuple.Item2)
                {
                    case LineTypes.LINE:
                        this.Graphics.DrawString((String)tuple.Item1, this.Font, this.SolidBrush, this.LeftMargin, this.YPosition(), new StringFormat());
                        this.LinesCount++;
                        break;
                    case LineTypes.IMAGE:
                        Image Image = (Image)tuple.Item1;

                        // Center Image, using PaperSize
                        Graphics GraphicsImage = Graphics.FromImage(Image);
                        RectangleF RectangleF = e.MarginBounds;
                        RectangleF.Offset(-e.PageSettings.HardMarginX, -e.PageSettings.HardMarginY);

                        float InchX = RectangleF.X / 100f + (RectangleF.Width / 100f - (float)Image.Width / GraphicsImage.DpiX) / 2f;
                        Int32 MillimeterX = (Int32)Math.Ceiling(InchX / 0.039370);

                        this.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, new Point((int)this.LeftMargin + (MillimeterX / 2), (int)this.YPosition()));
                        double a = (double)Image.Height / 58.0 * 15.0;
                        this.ImagesHeight += (int)Math.Round(a) + 3;
                        break;
                }
                if ((YPosition() * 4) >= e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height)
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = true;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

`YPosition` represent the height of each line or images in the pages.

How can I prevent the endless loop of printing and stop if all Objects are handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a for loop you need to use a while loop and an [Enumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx). The enumerator keeps the state of which object you're handling and that is stored as a member on the form instance. Use the [BeginPrint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.beginprint(v=vs.110).aspx) and [EndPrint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.endprint(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class to initialize and clean-up the enumerator.

```
// this is the variable that holds the enumerator instance 
// once printing has started
IEnumerator<Tuple<Object, LineTypes>> ObjectsEnumerator;

// this is the event raised by printdocument at the start of printing
private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    this.ObjectsEnumerator = Objects.GetEnumerator();
}
```

As we now have an enumerator the PrintPage implementation is going to use that. It calls [MoveNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx) and stores the result in `HasMorePages`. The rest of the code is similar to what you had but make sure to keep the calculation of the position on the page local to the method. Don't (ab)use instance variables for that. Notice the call to [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58e146b7(v=vs.110).aspx) as the first statement in the while loop.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int linesCount = 0;
    float yPosition = 10;
    // take the next item from the list by calling MoveNext
    // and assign the outcome to e.HasMorePages
    while(e.HasMorePages = this.ObjectsEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var tuple = this.ObjectsEnumerator.Current;
        switch (tuple.Item2)
        {
            case LineTypes.LINE:
                // draw magic
                e.Graphics.DrawString(tuple.Item1.ToString(), font, solidBrush, new PointF(10,yPosition));
                yPosition += 300;
                linesCount++;
                break;
            case LineTypes.IMAGE:
                Image Image = (Image)tuple.Item1;
                // e.Graphics.DrawImage(....);
                // calculate new yPosition
                yPosition += Image.Height;
                break;
        }
        // if we reach the end of the page
        if (yPosition >= e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height)
        {
            //we break out of the while loop
            // e.HasMorePages is already set
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

With this code you can iterate over your collection, break out of the loop if the page is full and stop iterating and printing when there are no more items to print.

If printing is done Endprint is called and its task is to clean-up the enumerator.

```
private void printDocument1_EndPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ObjectsEnumerator != null)
    {
        this.ObjectsEnumerator.Dispose();
        this.ObjectsEnumerator = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix pagination problem when printing in C# using HasMorePages.
Explanation about this code: You can add many rows or read from the database to see the result of pagination during printing, for example, I added only two rows to the table manually, which is not paginated because the number of rows is small. Add many rows manually or insert information from the database into the grid view. This is an example:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 36; //Number of rows per page
int rowIndex = 0;

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 5, y = 5; //Drawing start position
        int rowMargin = 0; //Spacing between lines

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        int rowCount = dgvHesaab.Rows.Count; //Get the number of rows
        int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(rowCount) / Convert.ToDouble(rowsPerPage)));

        //Set header content of columns
        for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            if (this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
            x += rect.Width;
        }

        x = 5;
        y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
        //Set the content of the lines
        while (rowIndex < dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvHesaab.Rows[rowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
                    }
                    x += rect.Width;
                }
                x = 5;
                y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
            }
            rowIndex++;

            //Print a new page if necessary
            if (rowIndex % rowsPerPage == 0 || rowIndex == dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPage < pageCount);
                currentPage++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

   
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab) 
        ///<summary>
        ///For example, the name of our Grid View is dgvHesaab
        ///Retrieving data from a database or manually inserting data for a row. 
        ///</summary>

        //add row 1
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 1 : Item 1",
            "Row 1 : Item 2",
            "Row 1 : Item 3",
            "Row 1 : Item 4",
            "Row 1 : Item 5",
            "Row 1 : Item 6",
        });

        //add row 2
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 2 : Item 1",
            "Row 2 : Item 2",
            "Row 2 : Item 3",
            "Row 2 : Item 4",
            "Row 2 : Item 5",
            "Row 2 : Item 6",
        });
        //End , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab)  

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        //Begin Print
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.AllowSelection = false;
        pDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
        pDialog.PrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.ShowHelp = false;
        pDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            pdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            pdoc.DocumentName = "Print Title";
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; //Landscape
            //pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pdoc;
            pdoc.Print(); //No preview  
            //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //printPreview
        }
        //End Print
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```