# PrintPage Event stays in endless loop while printing Chart Control

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, charts

I've found some issues on this but nothing that would help me in my logic. I have following code (showing not all because it would be too much):

```
 public int AreaCounter { get; set; } = 0;
 public PrintDocument pd { get; set; }

 public void PrintCharts(DataTable dt)
 {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
           //after a couple of rows - here is code for creating
           //a new chartArea and binding the points to the series
           //plus binding that series to the area

           if(// two chartAreas have been created with each one having a chart)
             {
               PrintChartControl();
             }
             AreaCounter++;
        }
 }

  private void PrintChartControl()
  {
    pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
    pd.Print();
  }

    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AreaCounter < 11) //12 ChartAreas have to be created
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            e.HasMorePages = false;

        var myRec = e.MarginBounds;
        Container.chart1.Printing.PrintPaint(e.Graphics, myRec);
    }
```

Now what I want to do:
I loop through a DataTable. Every few lines I create a new ChartArea, binding some values from this lines to a Series and bind this to the ChartArea. I'm actually drawing to ChartAreas to my Chart Control. Every two ChartAreas I print the Control, clean it, and draw the next two ChartAreas (there are 12 at the end - so 6 times drawing to the Chart Control). This works but I want to achieve the following:
I want to add a new page for every Chart Control to my print event so that I have 6 pages at the end and then print this to one file (pdf). Somehow it gets into an infinitive loop in the printPage Event because of the e.HasMorePages property. How does this work with the chart?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Where do you increment `AreaCounter`?

Comment: Sorry forgot about that. Edited the code

Comment: You have to bring your print logic and control of the loop inside the PrintPage event handler. See if [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32514337/578411) will help.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to use this in my case. Would IEnumerator<Tuple<Object, LineTypes>> ObjectsEnumerator; be my AreaCounter?

Comment: No, it would be your dt.Rows

Comment: Thought about that to but I i want to print a chart depending on a value changing in my datatable. That would be every couple rows. Could be 80 or more. Could you make an example?

Comment: I can not even call the GetEnumerator of my DataTable. Something does not work at all

Comment: You call Print() multiple times.  No, AreaCounter will always be 1 when you print the first one.  So you keep printing the same page over and over again.  Just delete the e.HasMorePages assignment completely, your print document has only one page.  Another bug is that you never set AreaCounter back to 0.  So you can print only once.

Comment: And how to achieve that I get 6 pages with each one having a printed chart control? I would be very glad about an example related to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better have the [`PrintDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class drive your data, instead of you trying to drive the `PrintDocument`. The PrintDocument class will raise a [`PrintPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage(v=vs.110).aspx) event, it is our task to provide the data for that single page. The data goes onto the `Graphics` instance provided in the [`PrintPageEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). If we want to print another page we make sure [`HasMorePages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages(v=vs.110).aspx) is true, the printdocument instance will call `PrintPage` again and we provide the data for the next page etc. When we have no more data and don't want more pages to be printed, we set `HasMorePages`to false.

Based on your code I created the following example that I expect to be applicable to your case.

I assumed the Rows in your DataTable are the main source to determine if and how many pages you need to print. If it is not based on that, you can create an Enumerator for a different collection/array, the mechanisms remain the same.

```
// the reference to the enumerator for the DataRows
IEnumerator rows;

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    var dataTable = Load();
    rows = dataTable.Rows.GetEnumerator();
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // no rows, no glory
    if (rows == null) return;

    // keep track of stuff
    var chartsOnthisPage = 0;
    var yPos = 20f;

    // loop for what needs to go on this page, atm it prints 2 charts
    // as long as there are rows
    // the enumerator is moved to the next record ...
    while ((e.HasMorePages = rows.MoveNext()))
    {
        // ... get hold of that datarow 
        var currentRow = (DataRow)rows.Current;

        // print
        e.Graphics.DrawString(currentRow[0].ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, 0, yPos);
        // keep track where we are
        yPos = yPos + 40;

        // do what ever is need to print the chart fro this row
        GenerateChart(currentRow);
        // print the chart
        chart1.Printing.PrintPaint(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(0, (int)yPos, 200, 200));
        // position tracking
        yPos = yPos + 200;
        // optionaly break here if we reached the end of the page
        // keep track 
        chartsOnthisPage++;
        if (chartsOnthisPage > 1) break; // HasMorePages is set
    }
}

private void printDocument1_EndPrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
   // clean up;
    rows = null;  
}
```

I have two helper methods, one to create a DataTable with rows and one to generate some *interesting* chart.

```
private DataTable Load()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("chart");

    for(int r=0; r<10; r++)
    {
        var rw = dt.NewRow();
        rw[0] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        dt.Rows.Add(rw);
    }
    return dt;
}

Random rnd = new Random();
private void GenerateChart(DataRow row)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add("data");
    var mx = rnd.Next(rnd.Next(10) + 3);
    for (int x = 0; x < mx; x++)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(x, rnd.Next(100));
    }
}
```

When I run this with a preview control this is what I get:

[image]