# Print multiple pages with Foreach (e.HasMorepages)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, foreach, printing

I have a question and i hope somebody can help me.

I would like to print a page, but if the page is longer than the first page than i would like to print multiple pages.
I've seen many code examples using e.HasMorePages.

**UPDATE**

This is my current code, it shows a second page but it's blank.
If it would be great if somebody can help me with this.

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument_BO_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument_BO.PrintPage


        Static page As Integer = 1
        Dim startPosition As Integer = (page - 1) * PrintDocument_BO.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Height
        Static maxPages As Integer = 0

        If page = 1 Then
            For Each ctrl1 As Control In PrintBackorder.PrintBO_panel.Controls
                If TypeOf ctrl1 Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl1 Is Label Or TypeOf ctrl1 Is PictureBox Then
                    ctrl1.Tag = Int((ctrl1.Top + ctrl1.Height) / PrintDocument_BO.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Height) + 1
                    If CInt(ctrl1.Tag) > maxPages Then maxPages = CInt(ctrl1.Tag)
                End If
            Next
            For Each ctrl2 As Control In PrintBackorder.BOLayoutPanel.Controls
                If TypeOf ctrl2 Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl2 Is Label Or TypeOf ctrl2 Is PictureBox Then
                    ctrl2.Tag = Int((ctrl2.Top + ctrl2.Height) / PrintDocument_BO.DefaultPageSettings.Bounds.Height) + 1
                    If CInt(ctrl2.Tag) > maxPages Then maxPages = CInt(ctrl2.Tag)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Dim sf = New StringFormat()
        For Each ctrl1 As Control In PrintBackorder.PrintBO_panel.Controls
            If CInt(ctrl1.Tag) = page Then
                If TypeOf ctrl1 Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl1 Is Label Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl1.Text, ctrl1.Font, Brushes.Black, ctrl1.Bounds.Location)

                ElseIf TypeOf ctrl1 Is PictureBox Then
                    'e.Graphics.DrawImage(DirectCast(ctrl, PictureBox).Image, New PointF(ctrl.Left, ctrl.Top - startPosition))

                    Dim myBitmap1 = New Bitmap(PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Width, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Height - 5)
                    'Dim myBitmap1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Width, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Height)
                    PrintBackorder.picBarcode.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap1, New Rectangle(0, 0, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Width, PrintBackorder.picBarcode.Height))
                    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality
                    'e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
                    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap1, 625, 50)

                End If
            End If
        Next
        For Each ctrl2 As Control In PrintBackorder.BOLayoutPanel.Controls 'PrintBackorder.PrintBO_panel.Controls
            If CInt(ctrl2.Tag) = page Then
                If TypeOf ctrl2 Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl2 Is Label Then

                    sf.Alignment = If(PrintBackorder.BOLayoutPanel.GetColumn(ctrl2) < 2, StringAlignment.Near, StringAlignment.Far)

                    e.Graphics.DrawString(ctrl2.Text, ctrl2.Font, Brushes.Black, PrintBackorder.PrintBO_panel.PointToClient(PrintBackorder.BOLayoutPanel.PointToScreen(ctrl2.Bounds.Location)), sf)

                End If
            End If
        Next

        page += 1
        If page > maxPages Then
            e.HasMorePages = False
            page = 1
            maxPages = 0
            MsgBox("done")
        Else
            e.HasMorePages = True
        End If
 End Sub
```

I know i shouldn't use a For Each loop but i don't know how to use a While loop in this case.

Comment: Don't use a `For Each` loop. Use a `For`, `Do` or `While` loop. You can then break out of the loop when you get to the end of the page and store the current position in a member variable. You can then pick up where you left off the next time the event handler is executed. Obviously that field would be initialised to zero when you start printing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i believe the anwser to this question is what i'm looking for and what you mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511364/printing-new-pages-with-e-hasmorepages but i'm having trouble applying it to my code, i've been trying all day. Can you help me?

Comment: If what you did didn't work then you did it wrong. We can't tell you what's wrong with it if we can't see it. Update your question with your best attempt to use the principle that's been explained and then we can help you fix it. ALWAYS provide ALL the relevant information.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm still stuck with this, i've updated the question with what i currently have,  It would be great if you can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general example of the principle provided in the comments:

```vb
'The data to be printed.
Private records As New List(Of String)

'The index of the next record to be printed.
Private recordIndex As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(...) Handles Button1.Click
    'Start printing from the first record.
    recordIndex = 0
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub

Private PrintDocument1_PrintPage(...) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Dim startRecordIndex = recordIndex

    'Print 10 records or, if there are not 10 records left, to the end of the list.
    Dim endRecordIndex = Math.Min(recordIndex + 9, records.Count - 1)

    For startRecordIndex To endRecordIndex
        Dim record = records(recordIndex)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(record, ...)
    Next

    'The next page will start at the next unprinted record if there is one.
    recordIndex = endRecordIndex + 1
    e.HasMorePages = recordIndex < records.Count
End Sub
```